# Top link not working in Firefox

Tags: jsp, firefox, hyperlink

We have one "Top" link at the bottom of each of the page in our application. Clicking on "Top" link navigates the page to the top (scroll bar goes up).

For this, we are maintaining a common piece of code in a common jsp

```
<a id="pagetop"></a>
```

While in all other JSP pages, the code looks like

```
<a href="#pagetop">Top</a>
```

The problem is that the top link is working fine for IE and chrome but the same is not working in firefox. Clicking on top link in firefox is not navigating the page up. Could you please fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is just working,

```
<html>

<body>
 <a id="pagetop">I am top</a>

<!-- pages of content goes here -->


 <a href="#pagetop">Top</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20fryokg/), you might have tagging mismatch.

Comment: for me it is not working. i have check the source file (by checking view source) but could not see any "Top" link property.

Comment: post your rendered HTML.